# Is it professional to ask for day off, after just few days in work, to attend friend's funeral?

Tags: meetings, holidays

My friend recently died and day of funeral is already known, but it's set to be on work day.

I just started working in new place and being inducted into company and project I'll be working on.

Also, I have some quite important video meetings planned for me in next days.

Is it professionally acceptable to ask for day off now, to attend the funeral or not?

Also, can my PM not allow me that day off, because of importancy of those meetings and should I just accept that decision?

Comment: If I was in your situation, I would definitely go regardless if it was professional or not (but of course telling the boss). No meeting can be as important as the last service for a friend. (But note that I have enough money to live for a few months without job and that my government cares for jobless people.)

Comment: Country matters

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Exactly, as the answer to this question is definitely specific to the countries labour-laws and regulations. In Austria and some other EU countries it's called 'Dienstverhinderung', which translates to the 'inability to attend'. Here the list of reason include the funeral of a close relative (while still being paid for that day), but excludes the funeral of a friend, in which case attending anyway could end up in being fired if things escalate..

Comment: Sooner you let them know, the better it is. Asking the day of will not go well in your favor especially if it is something you known ahead of time.

Answer (score 12):

> Is it professionally acceptable to ask for day off now, to attend the funeral or not?

If it was a close friend then yes, let your employer know that a very close friend has passed away and you would like a day to attend the funeral.

Depending on your country (instead of annual leave) you may or may not be able to take it as: **compassionate leave / Family Medical Leave / bereavement leave etc...**

There is nothing unprofessional about this. The timing may be unfortunate, but not in anyone's control.

> Can my PM not allow me that day off

All of this depends on your employment contract and country laws.

Comment: One addition: Make sure to ask as early as possible, so they can plan for your absence, reschedule your onboarding meetings etc.

Comment: Are there countries where the death of a friend would allow you to take compassionate leave instead of normal leave? Usually compassionate leave is reserved for family members in the first (and sometimes second) degree.

Comment: Yes there are. In the UK at least, while close family is primary, compassionate leave can extend to friends if you are close to them... I don't think it's a legal obligation of a company, but I can't imagine it being questioned.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it professionally acceptable to ask for day off now, to attend the
> funeral or not?

Certainly. It's always acceptable to ask for time to attend a funeral of a close friend or a family member.

Perhaps you don't need the full day. Perhaps you can offer to make up the lost time somehow.

Sorry for your loss.

Answer (score 7):

It is professional.  To make sure, you can offer to bring a prayer card, or a program from the funeral.  They will probably tell you not to bother, but approach your manager immediately, explain your situation, and then ask about going to HR.

You may want to approach HR directly, and see what their policy is, but let them know ASAP.

Don't say: *"Can I.."*

Say: *"I need to take the day/afternoon off because a friend of mine just passed away, do I need to bring anything back from the funeral home for your records?"*

Answer (score 0):

It definitely is professional to *ask* for time off to attend the funeral for a friend or family.  In most locales, such a request should be granted.  At least in my locale we have bereavement leave which this would probably qualify for.  Your locale may be different.  You may want to ask the company if they need some kind of proof that you did attend the funeral, and provide whatever you can if asked.

If your request to attend the funeral is denied, I would respect the company's wishes to not go to the funeral (and make profuse apologies to your friend's family), but then immediately start looking for a new job.  Not allowing you to attend the funeral of a friend is very disrespectful; that would be a no-deal flag for me to continue working at the company.

Comment: If you plan to switch jobs regardless, why would you not go to the funeral? They aren't going to be happy either way

Comment: @JSLavertu Because I might not find a new job immediately, and I'd rather collect a paycheque in the meantime than be unemployed.  With very few exceptions, don't quit your job until you have another lined up.